# Rails passing value between actions in a same controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This is my controller :

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :get_date

        def show

             @school = School.where(city_namespace: params[:city], title_namespace: params[:title]).first || raise(ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found'))

        end

     private
       # get meeting date dynamically
       # TODO: Access to date value in schools#show action 
     def get_date
        @date = params[:date]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => @date.as_json }
        end
     end 
end
```

the get_date method retrieve a date with an ajax call :

```
$('.next-step').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var date = $('td.day.active').data('day');
     $.post('/get_date', {
       date: date
     });
});
```

But when I use before_action, I have this error :

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

And I can't access `@date` in the show action, but I have to, to display it in my view here :

```
<div class="scheduler--picker-line-item <% if @school.meeting_already_booked?(@date, "#{time}:00") %>scheduler--picker-line-item--disabled <% end %>" data-value="<%= time %>:00">
```

With the method that come from the school model :

```
  def meeting_already_booked?(date, hour)
    meeting_token = Meeting.find_by(date: date, mhour: hour)
    if !meeting_token.nil?
      puts true
      return true
    else
      puts false
      return false
    end
  end
```

Does someone know what is this error ? and how could I access to @date variable in the show method ?

**EDIT**

The loggs

```
Started GET "/auto-ecoles/paris/paris/auto-ecole-du-chateau" for ::1 at 2017-06-14 14:31:49 +0200
Processing by SchoolsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"department"=>"paris", "city"=>"paris", "title"=>"auto-ecole-du-chateau"}

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms
** [Raven] Event not sent due to excluded environment: development

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:219:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:95:in `get_date'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:189:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:167:in `call'
  rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  browser (0.6.0) lib/browser/middleware.rb:51:in `run_app'
  browser (0.6.0) lib/browser/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:45:in `call'
  bullet (4.14.5) lib/bullet/rack.rb:10:in `call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  sentry-raven (0.13.3) lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.2.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.2.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/server.rb:287:in `start'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:8:in `require'
  bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.3.4) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/spring:13:in `require'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT**

```
  post '/get_date' => 'schools#get_date', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Comment: what does your `params[:date]` look like?

Comment: When I was able to `puts @date` it was a json object like this : `{"date": "12/09/2017"}`

Comment: so why do you even want to convert? use `@date` directly

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon when i remove .as_json, I still have the same error

Comment: What is is the request format that is displayed in the server log? Also try adding `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @Pavan What do you mean by Request format ? and where I'm suppose to add dataType: 'json' ?

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` in the script. And post the log in the question when the request hits the controller

Comment: @Pavan Just adding the loggs in my question as edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:defaults => { :format => 'json' }` to the route for that action, like so:

```
get 'get_date', to: 'school#get_date', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Just re-check the variables as I'm not familiar with your routes.

Adding dataType might also fix it, as Md. Farhan said.

```
 $.post('/get_date', {
   date: date,
   dataType: "json"
 });
```

Comment: if I add `:default => { :format => 'json' }`I still have the same error  : ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: Adding `dataType: "json"` as Md. Farhan said will also help. Will edit the answer to show how.

Comment: I have already added `dataType: "json"` but I still having this error, I don't understand why this error occur

Comment: This might be a long shot, but can you try changing the format.json line to match this syntax

`format.json { render json: @date} `

Comment: Still not work .. why is "unknow format" ? Maybe there is an other solution to get the value of @date in the show method?

Comment: can you update the post with your routes.rb? it's also possible that you're not matching it to :post (I'm also pretty stumped as what I suggested earlier worked for my previous project, which had two separate ajax calls)

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what's wrong with it either. What if you remove the before_action line? You're calling it via ajax so I don't understand why it's in your before_action.

Comment: I use before_action before I need to access `@date` that is in get_date method, in show method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146679/discussion-between-hans-cristobal-and-antonin-mrchd).